# генетический алгоритм учится управлять машинами

Tags: javascript, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, генетический-алгоритм

Я хочу сделать генетический алгоритм для управления машинами на JS без библиотек.

Написал нейронку, которая принимает на вход расстояние до стены в пяти направлениях (0, 45, 90, 270 и 315 градусов), а на выходе выдает два значения, каждое может быть равно -1, 0 или 1 и показывает должна ли машина ехать вперед, назад или стоять на месте, а также должна ли она поворачивать вправо, влево или соответственно ехать прямо. Структура сети: 5 входных нейронов, 4 - нейрона на скрытом слое и 2 - выходных нейрона.

Далее я создаю 80 автомобилей, чтобы они попытались проехать трассу. Если машина касается стены - попытка считается не удачной. Пройденное расстояние определяется по количеству зеленых линей, которые машина пересекает за отведенное время (они разбросаны по всей карте, а на рисунке ниже отображается только следующая метка каждой машины).

Как только время на одно поколение заканчивается, я получаю данные о пройденном расстоянии от всех машин, суммирую и для каждой машины делю пройденное расстояние на эту сумму.

Таким образом я получаю вероятность, с которой эта машина будет выбрана как родитель для следующего поколения.

Затем я выбираю два родителя и комбинирую их веса. Сколько весовых коэффициентов каждого слоя будет взято от каждого родителя выбирается случайно для каждого потомка. Также с вероятностью 10% я добавляю или вычитаю 0.1 из текущего коэффициента, то есть произвожу мутацию. Также я ограничиваю значение веса диапазоном от -1.5 до 1.5.

Вот как это происходит для скрытого слоя:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5 * eduParams.hiddenLayer; i++) {
        if (i / (5 * eduParams.hiddenLayer) > Math.random() && currentParent === parent1) {
            currentParent = parent2;
        }

        //если шанс мутации сработал, генерируется прибавка или -прибавка, иначе 0
        let mutation = Math.random() < eduParams.mutationChance ? (1 - (Math.round(Math.random()) * 2)) * eduParams.mutation : 0;

        //взять вес от родителя и прибавить к нему мутацию
        let weight = limit(currentParent[0][i] + mutation, -eduParams.weightLimit, eduParams.weightLimit);

        newWeights[0].push(weight);
    }
```

Затем я повторяю всё сначала. В чём же у меня проблема я думаю вы уже догадались - в том, что они не могут ничему обучится. Я не знаю по какой причине, но они даже не могут пройти первый поворот, и либо поворачивают сразу же и врезаются в стену, либо едут по прямой и всё. Я давал им где-то 90 поколений на обучение.

Выглядит это вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, подскажите что я делаю не так.

Вот, что я уже пробовал:

1. В скрытом слое поставить побольше нейронов: 15, 20.
2. Добавить больше лучей: 10.
3. Сделать лучи длиннее, короче.
4. Сделать так, чтобы для каждого потомка выбирались два новых случайных родителя.
5. Сделать больше машин в одном поколении: 200.
6. Увеличить, уменьшить вероятность мутации: 5%, 20%.

Я делал так как это по каким-то обрывкам информации с ютуба и скорее всего чего-то не догоняю. Подскажите - что.

Спустя некоторое время игры с параметрами, я поставил 10 лучей, 20 нейронов на скрытом слое, по два случайных родителя на одного потомка и получил следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первый поворот ИИ всё таки прошел, но дальше этого дело пока не идёт.